# Vue Router, Are there a way to retain the query from previous page with Navigation guard

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-router

As the topic say, I just want to carry the query from the current page to the next page without having to explicitly put it in all of my push function, but instead maybe just Navigation guard or some hooks?

I have researched some out article and tried:

Case 1: the to.query is read-only

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // Access query parameters from the previous page (from)
  const previousQuery = from.query;

  // Attach the query parameters to the next page (to)
  // For example, if you want to pass all query parameters to the next page:
  const newQuery = { ...to.query, ...previousQuery };

  // Update the query parameters for the next page
  to.query = newQuery;

  // Continue with navigation
  next();
});
```

Error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: "query" is read-only

Case 2:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // Access query parameters from the previous page (from)
  const previousQuery = from.query;

  // Attach the query parameters to the next page (to)
  // For example, if you want to pass all query parameters to the next page:
  const newQuery = { ...to.query, ...previousQuery };

  // Create a new URL with the updated query parameters
  const newUrl = { ...to, query: newQuery };

  // Continue with navigation to the new URL
  next(newUrl);
});
```

Error:
Somehow, this code yield an infinity loop. I guess it because of next function doing its recursive.

Case ETC,:
I have read the document that said next() troublesomes and try to return instead of next() however the page didn't move nothing happens.

Thank in advance. I totally out of ideas now.

Comment: You can clone it and store it in global store. Probably the interaction between pages could be done through a store in the first place instead of url

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is using state management - such as [Pinia (previously know as Vuex).](https://pinia.vuejs.org/)

You can add a *store* (which is global) that holds something like:

```
export const useQueryStore = defineStore('queries', {
  state: () => ({ lastQuery: undefined }),
  getters: {
    getLastQuery: (state) => state.lastQuery,
    hasQueried: (state) => state.lastQuery !== undefined,
  },
  actions: {
    onQuery(query) {
      this.lastQuery = query;
    },
  },
})
```

You can set the query done by calling *setQuery(query)*.

Then you can access the store with:

```
import { useQueryStore } from '@/stores/query';

// in a component
const queryStore = useQueryStore()

// in your navigation guard:
...{
    const hasQueried = queryStore.hasQueried

    if(hasQueried) {
        // do something with what returns from queryStore.getLastQuery()
    }
}...
```

Not the most optimal solution, but just a rough example that may help you.